# Bit shifting and data explanation

Tags: c#, java, c++, c

Ok, I'd like to have an explanation on how bit shifting works and how to build data from an array of bytes.The language is not important (if an example is needed, I know C,C++, Java and C#, they all follow the same shifting syntax,no?)

The question is, how do I go from byte[] to something which is a bunch of bytes together? (be it 16 bit ints, 32 bits ints, 64 bit ints, n-bits ints) and more importantly, why? I'd like to understand and learn how to make this myself rather then copy from the internet.
I know of endianess, I mainly mess with little endian stuff, but explaining a general rule for both systems would be nice.
Thank you very very much!!
Federico

Comment: this is two questions. Do you want to know how bit shifting works or know how arrays are created?...

Comment: I'd like to know how to go from an array of bytes to a single data type which is made of more than one byte.

Answer (score 3):

for bit shifting i would say. byte1 << n will shift bits of byte1 to n times left and result can be get by multiplying byte1 with 2^n...and for >>n we have to divide byte1 by 2^n.

Answer (score 2):

Hm... it depends what you're looking for. There's really no way to convert to an n-bit integer type (it's always an array of bytes anyways) but you can shift bytes into other types.

```
my32BitInt = byte1 << 24 | byte2 << 16 | byte3 << 8 | byte4
```

Comment: thank you! this actually makes sense now!! I got it! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Usually the compiler is going to take care of endianess for you. So you can OR bytes together with shifting and not worry too much about that.

I've used a bit of a cheat myself in the past to save cycles. When I know the data to be in arrays least to most significant order, then you can cast the bytes into larger types and walk the array by size of walker. For example this sample walks 4 bytes at a time and writes 4 byte ints in C.

```
char bytes[] = {1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1};
int *temp;
temp = (int *)&bytes[0];
printf("%d\n", *temp);
temp = (int *)&bytes[4];
printf("%d\n", *temp);
temp = (int *)&bytes[8];
printf("%d\n", *temp);
temp = (int *)&bytes[12];
printf("%d\n", *temp);

return 0;
```

Output:
    1
    256
    65536
    16777216

This is probably no good for C# and Java

Comment: C# equivalent is the `BitConverter` class.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to to take into consideration the endianness of the data. From there, it depends on the data type - but here is an example. Let's say you would like to go from an array of 4 bytes to an unsigned 32 bit integer. Let's also assume the bytes are in the same order as they started (so we don't need to worry about the endianness ).

```
//In C
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t offset; //the offset in the array, should be set to something
uint32_t unpacked_int; //target
uint8_t* packed_array; //source

for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < 4; --i ) {
    unpacked_int += packed_array[ offset + i ] << 8*i;
```

You could equivalently use |= and OR the bytes too. Also, if you attempt this trick on structures be aware that your compiler probably won't pack values in back-to-back, although usually you can set the behavior with a pragma. For example, gcc/g++ packs data aligned to 32 bits on my architecture.

On C#, BitConverter should have you covered. I know Python, PHP, and Perl use a function called pack() for this, perhaps there is an equivalent in Java.